# SVG Animation hide or stop after page load?

Tags: jquery, html, performance, svg, css-animations

I am displaying an SVG / CSS loading animation on page load and I usually hide the `<div>` that contains the SVG / CSS after the page load. 

Is there any **performance issue** there when we hide the `<div>` without stopping animation? Is it necessary to stop animation after hiding the SVG animation? Both in case of SVG and CSS animation?

Comment: On what browser? On what version of that browser? Any answer we gave might be obsolete the next time a new version comes out. This is pretty much going to be try it and see on the browsers/operating systems/versions you are concerned about.

Answer (score 1):

It depends how you hide your element and how your animation works. If it's pure css and if you specify display:none, the browser have the information not to render the specified element. If you hide it with another element above it, the browser will still attempt to render it. In all case, if you have a script to manage animation, you have to stop it.
However if you really want to be sure :
https://dev.webonomic.nl/how-to-disable-css-transforms-transistions-and-animations/comment-page-1

Comment: using jquery hide() or similar function to hide which in fact set display:none